# Ruby-модуль YAML не выполняет .load для yaml-строки (Psych::DisallowedClass)

Tags: ruby, yaml

Иду по самоучителю Ruby. Моя задача понять как объекты сохранять в yaml-строки и восстанавливать обратно с помощью стандартного модуля YAML, но я столкнулся с учебным кодом, который завершается ошибкой:

```
require 'yaml'

class Person
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :patronymic, :password
  def initialize(first_name:, last_name:, patronymic:, password:)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @patronymic = patronymic
    @password = password
  end
end

person = Person.new(
  first_name: 'Иван',
  last_name: 'Петрович',
  patronymic: 'Сидоров',
  password: 'qwerty'
)

yaml_str = YAML.dump(person)    # интересует именно эта часть кода,
recovered = YAML.load(yaml_str) # чтобы восстановить объект из той же переменной

p recovered.first_name # "Иван"
p recovered.last_name  # "Петрович"
p recovered.patronymic # "Сидоров"
p recovered.password   # "qwerty"
```

Программа выводит следующее:

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/class_loader.rb:99:in `find': Tried to load unspecified class: Person (Psych::DisallowedClass)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/class_loader.rb:28:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:424:in `resolve_class'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:213:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:318:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych.rb:335:in `safe_load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `load'
        from C:/Users/armoy/OneDrive/Documents/selflearning_book/FTP/modules/yaml_load.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

Gem psych-4.0.3.
Утилита ri для метода load модуля YAML ничего любопытного вроде не пишет об этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема не в `dump`, а в `load`.

В геме psych полгода назад случились довольно серьёзные изменения, и метод `load` стал более безопасным, разучившись работать со сложными структурами данных. Вот [здесь](https://github.com/ruby/psych/pull/487) подробнее про это.

Для доверенных источников есть метод `unsafe_load`, воспользуйтесь им

Answer (score 0):

Лучше вообще не дампить объекты, потому что там yaml специфический получается. Если надо сохранять и восстанавливать объект, то его следует сперва сериализовать в хэш, а потом восстанавливать из хэша. Например, добавить такой метод:

```
def as_hash
  {
      first_name: @first_name,
      last_name: @last_name,
      patronymic: @patronymic,
      password: @password
  }
end
```

И потом вот так сохранять и читать:

```
yaml_str = YAML.dump(person.as_hash)
recovered = Person.new(**YAML.load(yaml_str))
```